# Calling a procedure from drupal

Tags: database

I have a procedure structure like this in an Oracle database:

```
procedure overlapping_course (
  v_id  number,
  v_program varchar2,
  v_message_type  varchar2,
  v_user_type varchar2,
  v_language  varchar2, 
  v_channel varchar2,
  v_country varchar2,
  v_start_date  date,
  v_end_date  date,
 v_return_val  out varchar2
 )
```

I am trying to call this procedure from Drupal 7 and I am following [this](http://public-action.org/content/stored-procedures-and-drupal-7) link. My code looks like this:

```
 $conn = Database::getConnection();
 $saved_class = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('PDOStatement')); 
 $statement = $conn->prepare('call overlapping_course(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');    

$statement->bindParam(1, $id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

$id=1;

$statement->bindParam(1, $program,PDO::PARAM_STRING);

$program='c++';
 -------
 --------
```

but I am always getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DatabaseStatementPrefetch::bindParam()   in C:\Apache24\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\oracle\database.inc on line 655.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the problem, but after adding the  following piece of code in my database.ini of oracle directory and changing my calling method prepare('-----') to oraclePrepare('-------') I am able to access the stored procedure with parameters. I got the reference from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1336718#comment-5228686)

Check for the oraclePrepare('-------') method in database.ini. If it is not there then add following lines in the DatabaseConnection_oracle class.

code Added in DatabaseConnection_oracle class of oracle's database.ini:

```
 public function oraclePrepare($query)
 {
     return parent::prepare($query);
  }
```